# Request No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Only with POST request

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm sorry for asking this, but I'm dealing with cakePHP 3.x since only 2 days, and I can't see what's wrong. 
I'm requesting a POST request from cakePHP application, but I keep getting the error with POST request (GET request is fine), I'm using the below lines of code at `middleware` method, what else should I do? and Is this the proper way for activate CORS domain?

```
Application.php
  ->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
            return $next($request, $response)
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')             
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Type', 'application/json');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this tool to fix this issue instead of adding any code to the Application file:
https://github.com/ozee31/cakephp-cors